# How to call a method of python3.x script inside a python2.x script

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, class, subprocess

I have two scripts one in python2.x and another one is python3.x
I have to call a method present inside python3.x from inside a python2.x script.

This is what I've tried so far :

python2.x file :

**Method 1 :**

```py
class ServiceOne:
    #constructor
    #more methods
    def process(self):
        cmd = ["/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3.9", "-c", "import logging; 
              from python3file import ServiceTwo; service = ServiceTwo(%r,logging);
              service.mymethod()" % repr(self)]
            try:
                subprocess.call(cmd)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print("Error occurred while running the subprocess : %s" %str(e))

       return True
```

**Method 2 :**

```py
class ServiceOne:
    #constructor
    #more methods
    def process(self):
        pickled_self = pickle.dumps(self)
        cmd = ["/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python3.9", "-c", "import logging;
              import pickle; from python3file import ServiceTwo; 
              unpickled_self = pickle.loads(sys.argv[1]); 
              service = ServiceTwo(unpickled_self,logging);
              service.mymethod()" % pickled_self]
            try:
                subprocess.call(cmd)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                print("Error occurred while running the subprocess : %s" %str(e))

       return True
```

And this is how my python3 code looks like :

```py
class ServiceTwo:
    def __init__(self, params, logging):
        #doing some stuff
    def mymethod(self):
        #doing more stuff
```

**Method1** throws a syntax Error, rightly so.
**Method2** throws errors like `can't pickle file objects` or `can't pickle instancemethod objects`

How can I pass the self instance correctly here.

Comment: Try adding `print(' '.join(cmd))` before the try/except block to see what command is being run. As long as you can sort out the correct syntax to instantiate `ServiceTwo` from the Python 3 interpreter, you'll be able to figure out what `cmd` should look like.

Comment: @Noah I tried using pickle to do that, but it can't pickle file objects or instancemethod objects. So... again stuck with that. Do you have any solution in mind worth trying? Any way by which I don't have to alter self attributes and just be able to pass it in some way.

Comment: just pass the parameters needed to create the `ServiceTwo` object. for example if instead of `ServiceTwo` you had a class called `Dog` takes `color` and `age` as parameters, your command would contain something like `pet = Dog("black",13)`. If there are a lot of parameters, you can save them in a json file in your python 2 program and load them in your python 3 program. If what you try doesn't work for whatever reason, it's helpful to **read the documentation and tutorials**.

Comment: @Noah So I tried something similar. I created a python dictionary and only included the specific attributes of self which are required in my python3 code. The catch is that out of the all attributes which I've added to the dictionary two of them are of type instance and instancemethod, others are just either file names or paths which are quite easy to pickle and pass to cmd. I've searched a lot but couldn't anything of importance where I could find the best way to pass these type of attributes.

Comment: you don't pass them. `instance` is the `ServiceOne` class instance. you just need to pass the parameters `ServiceTwo` needs. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't serialize the whole class instance like that, just pass parameters you need to create a `ServiceTwo` object from scratch. If there are a lot of parameters, dump them to a json file.

Comment: I see, but I do need to pass these two instances as well. Is there any way that could be achieved?

Comment: Or atleast one instance that is a ```ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser``` instance